# Check if a string is a date

Tags: php

I have some dynamic date values that I am trying to change to a human-readable format. Most of the strings I get are in the format `yyyymmdd`, for example 20120514, but some are not. I need to skip the ones that re not in that format, because they may be not dates at all.

How do I add such check to my code?

```
date("F j, Y", strtotime($str))
```

Comment: Not quite understanding what you mean, you want to check if the string you get is of YYYYMMDD format? Or you want to make sure it's not?

Answer (score 7):

You could use this function for the purpose:

```
/**
 * Check to make sure if a string is a valid date.
 * @param $str   String under test
 *
 * @return bool  Whether $str is a valid date or not.
 */
function is_date($str) {
    $stamp = strtotime($str);
    if (!is_numeric($stamp)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $month = date('m', $stamp);
    $day   = date('d', $stamp);
    $year  = date('Y', $stamp);
    return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```

[@source](http://www.tim-carter.com/index.php?t=Check+if+string+is+a+date+with+PHP&Menu=2&SubMenuId=5&ItemId=72)

Comment: Could be simplified to `return checkdate($month, $day, $year)` and please for the love of god use curly brackets!

Answer (score 4):

For a quick check, `ctype_digit` and `strlen` should do:

```
if(!ctype_digit($str) or strlen($str) !== 8) {
    # It's not a date in that format.
}
```

You can be more thorough with [`checkdate`](http://php.net/checkdate):

```
function is_date($str) {
    if(!ctype_digit($str) or strlen($str) !== 8)
        return false;

    return checkdate(substr($str, 4, 2),
                     substr($str, 6, 2),
                     substr($str, 0, 4));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use regular expressions to check if the string has 8 digits.

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{8}$/', $date)) {
    // This checks if the string has 8 digits, but not if it's a real date
}
```

Comment: and if the string is `87459235`? :)

Comment: Why? There are simpler (and more efficient) ways than regex.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: Hey, maybe in the year `8745`, there will be `95` months.  Why not? :-P

Comment: @Rocket that's **very** optimistic to believe that your script still be in use in year 8745 :)

Comment: True guys, was just thinking of checking that the characters are digits.. Answer above would have same problem then?

Comment: @ZoltanToth Even though is not necessary to use a regex, the upvoted answer has the same problem of not checking strings like 87459235.

Comment: @Nobita: Yes, but it's not meant to. A regular expression is probably the most inefficient way possible to perform this simple check.

Comment: @minitech I know, but some of the comments above are being critique with the fact that is not checking if a year is 8745, and this check is not being done in your answer either. That's all :)